# How to change a photograph into a cartoon?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've been using Photoshop for a couple of years now so I'm not completely new. Recently I discovered this T-Shirt I really like, and then found the original image that was used to make it. Or maybe inspire it. 
The question I have been trying to figure out is, how can someone do this? I've tried several different methods / filters but can't seem to achieve something that looks this nice. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]
[image]

Comment: While there're methods to convert photos to illustrations with a particular style (using neural networks trained on specific art styles, for example https://deepart.io/), I think in this case an artist painted on top of the photo or used it as a reference to actually make the illustration, not applied a filter to the photo. So simple answer to 'how to achieve this' would be 'to paint this'.

Comment: That image is drawn using the photo as a *reference* to look at. It's not a "run an action on a photo" image.

Comment: I would like to know how to turn a drawing into a photograph :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's a drawing, very likely it's partially drawn having the photo below, because it makes a clear goal. I have done it numerous times when someone has given a photo and wanted a resembling drawing. I worked in Inkscape because its drawing tools fitted the job. Cartoonizing filters are for those who want to avoid drawing.

Cartoonizing filter will not make it because they cannot see what is essential. One can help filters by separating the wanted objects with clipping paths to separate layers and applying the filter object by object. If you apply cartoonizing to whole photo, you get something like the next (at best):

[image]

It's totally useless to try to insert the strokes in the filtering, because there are far too much details. It would be an useless mess. But clipping the wanted objects to separate layers before filtering and painting unwanted details to flat would help. Also stretch the contrast to the maximum for every object separately.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app from Synthetik, called [Studio Artist](https://synthetik.com), which does that type of thing.

At its simplest, you feed it an image,  press a button to run a preset & see if you like the result.
You can go at it with a Wacom & pen, & it will better follow your intent.
You can alternatively just spend days fiddling with presets - it's a fascinating way to waste a day ;-)

This is just a couple of very quick examples using some of the simpler, faster presets...

None of them are particularly like your example, but not a million miles away considering I spent a whole 10 minutes on it ;)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This result is **not a direct result of applying one filter**.

The trees on the background are not in the original photo for example.

Some of the dogs are too dark and lack of contrast so no app can yet detect what is there on that dark zone.

The image is used as a reference to be drawn on top.

[image]

- Resample your image, make the canvas of the desired final size.
- Put a new layer on top of the image.
- Start drawing. A Drawing tablet will help you a lot.
- Remember to work in layers, for the black strokes, for the brown color, for each dog, for the truck, etc...

---

I must say. This is the process for this particular style and particular case. There are other techniques, some of them can be applying just a couple of filters, but this depends on the filter, the original image, and the desired result.

There are a lot of filter programs, some standalone, some plugins. Here is a couple of results of one program called Filter Forge.

[image]

[image]

Some preparation might be needed, for example masking the individual heads of the dogs so the program can apply the same amount of dark ink on each of them, cleaning unnecessary detail on the background, etc.

You can also make a cartoonish proportion using some liquify to change the proportions of the truck for example.

[image]

[image]

But for now, the best option is to manually do it. I'm sure AI based filters will make some decent job in the not so distant future...